# Question about Katoolin is being close voted as off-topic because it's "not about Ubuntu"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question [Updated Ubuntu 16.04, now I'm running Kali?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834132/updated-ubuntu-16-04-now-im-running-kali) is not about Kali Linux, it's about a problem that occurred because of installing software in Ubuntu using Katoolin. I discovered what happened after the OP added an explanation of what happened to the accepted answer as an update.

I'm frustrated that this keeps happening, even though the usage of Katoolin is clearly explained in the [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin) tag. However neither the OP nor the 4 reviewers who close voted this question noticed this because the question didn't have the Katoolin tag. The question wasn't properly tagged when it was reviewed, so I have no right to complain, but I don't want it to be closed for two reasons.

1. The question adds context to other questions about Katoolin.
2. The question has a valuable answer.

If this question is closed anyway, I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: The 3 close votes are not in the review queue.

Comment: Retracted my own close vote.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question about Katoolin has not been closed, and now it shows that there aren't any close votes. I think the root of the problem is that new users who want ask a question about using Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu search for an appropriate tag, and all they find is [kali](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali) so they read the [kali](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali) tag excerpt which says:

> Questions that are only about Kali and not about Ubuntu are off-topic here! Please ask them on Unix & Linux Q&A.

Then they give up and don't use a Kali tag because there isn't a separate tag for [kali-linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux-tools). Since there wasn't a [kali-linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux-tools) tag, I made one and suggested that it be made into a synonym for [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin). If you are a user who a total answer score of 5 or more on the [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin) tag, you can visit the ['katoolin' Tag Synonyms](https://askubuntu.com/tags/katoolin/synonyms) page and vote to make [kali-linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux-tools) a synonym for [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin).

*Update:* The question has been used as a duplicate link for questions about the same problem like this one: [Distribution Name Incorrect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931089/distribution-name-incorrect) which proves that the problem in the question is reproducible. Rinzwind's answer is the more specific one for this question.

Comment: I’d suggest synonymising the other direction. One is w lot clearer than the other.